# AngularJS - ng-click - ng-class - toggle disabled/enabled

Tags: angularjs

**I have this table row:**

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="truckWheelbase in truckWheelbases | orderBy:sortFunction" ng-click="toggleRow($index)">                            
   <td>
      <!--Wheelbase-->                    
      <label class="checkbox" for="{{truckWheelbase.Id}}">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.Ids[truckWheelbase.Id]" id="{{truckWheelbase.Id}}">
            {{truckWheelbase.WheelBaseGrade}} - {{truckWheelbase.Inches}} inches
      </label>
   </td>
   <!--Payload-->  
   <td>
      <input id="{{truckWheelbase.Payload}}" type="number" ng-class="getClass({{truckWheelbase.Id}})">
   </td>
</tr>
             .......remaining rows ............
</table>
```

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

At the onset of page load all the controls for each table row are disabled **except the check box controls in column 1**.

When the user checks/unchecks the respective row's check box, all the controls in that row are enabled/disabled.

I am not having much success but I am sure **ng-class** is required and the **toggleRow($index)** in the controller will set the class to disabled="disabled" or just blank.

Any ideas?

**Illustration:**

[image]

**bmleite**

**ng-disabled="!selection.Ids[truckWheelbase.Id]"**  does indeed disable all the controls on page load, but how do I implement **ng-class="getClass({{truckWheelbase.Id}})"** to enable on check box click?

Comment: Instead of `ng-class="..."`, try `ng-disabled="selection.Ids[truckWheelbase.Id]"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your `toggleRow()` function is doing exactly but I assume it is changing the `selection.Ids` object. If that's the case, you just need to use that same information to enable/disable the inputs. For that, use the `ng-disabled` directive:

```
<!--Payload-->  
<td>
    <input id="{{truckWheelbase.Payload}}" type="number" ng-class="getClass({{truckWheelbase.Id}})" 
           ng-disabled="!selection.Ids[truckWheelbase.Id]">
</td>
```